# yii2 format data output of listview into 4x4 grid

Tags: listview, yii2, grid

I have in view

```
echo ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_list',
]);
```

where _list is layout file where I can design output of each component.
But all components are shown one after another in a column.

And I want to show them 4 x 4 square format for example.
What is the best practice for it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know your styling, but this one should work.

```
echo ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_list',
    'itemOptions' => [
        'class' => 'item-class',
    ],
    'options' => ['class' => 'parent-class'],    
    'layout' => "<div class='parent-class'>{items}</div>"
]);
```

Use this block of code, with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6sjbavn/).

Comment: Works great but one problem. No pagination if I use such configuration.
Probably that's because too much customization in ListView configuration ???? Should I add it somehow there manually ?

Comment: In last setting just add **{pager**}, like this.
`'layout' => "<div class='parent-class'>{items}\n{pager}</div>"`

Comment: Here you can read about [layout](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-baselistview.html#$layout-detail).

Answer (score 1):

In a column? Not in a row?
I think this is because of some styles in your project.
You can place elements from ListView in any order by styling.
I prefer using css3 flexbox, take a look here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.
You can setup classes for each item and their parent and style them as you wish (All available options you can find here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html).

```
echo ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_list',
    'itemOptions' => [
        'class' => 'item-class',
    ],
    'options' => ['class' => 'parent-class'],    
    'layout' => "<div class='parent-class'>{items}</div>"
]);
```

Comment: can u write simple example of how do it for x x x x then second row x x x x then so on and so on ?